# C# count of labels or textboxs in win form

Tags: c#, label

How Can i retrieve number of labels in winform dynamicly? Because in my form i have about 12 labels and if i press button i want to change every label to textbox. So in sum I want to make every label editable and after editing and save change it back to label. In summary it will be like editable label.
But it take lot of time and rows in code to write change for every label, so if it is possible to make it dynamic i will be perfect. Thanks.[image: This is an example]

Comment: It should be possible to count the lables, but I don't think it is possible to change the type of a control (label <-> textbox) at runtime.

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You may want to have `TextBox` with `BackColor = Colors.Control`, `BorderStyle = None` and `ReadOnly = true` to emulate `Label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest have `TextBox`es, not `Label`s to contain any text which can be edited. 
So we have `TextBox` in **2** different modes *Label Mode* (no editing) and *TextBox Mode*.
To switch between them (assuming *WinForms*):

```
// Make TextBox to look like a label: readonly, color, border etc.
private static void ToLabelMode(TextBox box) {
  if (null == box)
    return;

  box.HideSelection = true;
  box.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
  box.ReadOnly = true;
  box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
}

private static void ToTextBoxMode(TextBox box) {
  if (null == box)
    return;

  box.HideSelection = false;
  box.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
  box.ReadOnly = false;
  box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
}
```

Then you can use them:

```
TextBox[] m_TextBoxes;

private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  m_TextBoxes = new TextBox[] {
    textBoxFirstName, 
    textBoxLastName, 
    //TODO: Put the relevant ones
  };

  // Let all TextBox be in Label mode
  EnableEdit(false);
}

private void EnableEdit(bool enabled) {
  foreach (var box in m_TextBoxes)
    if (enabled)
      ToTextBoxMode(box);
    else 
      ToLabelMode(box); 
}
```

**Edit:** If you *insist* on having `Label` and `TextBox` I suggest having both of them and use `Visible` to show the right control (either `Label` or corresponding `TextBox`):

```
Dictionary<Label, TextBox> m_TextBoxesPairs;

private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  m_TextBoxesPairs = new Label[] {
    labelFirstName,
    labelSecondName,
    //TODO: put all the relevant labels here
  }
  .ToDictionary(lbl => lbl,
                lbl => new TextBox() {
                  Parent   = lbl.Parent,
                  Text     = lbl.Text,
                  Location = lbl.Location,
                  Size     = lbl.Size,
                  Visible  = false
                });

  // If you want to modify Label.Text on TextBox.Text changing
  foreach (var pair in m_TextBoxesPairs)
    pair.Value.TextChanged += (o, ee) => {pair.Key.Text = pair.Value.Text;} 

  EnableEdit(false);  
}

private void EnableEdit(bool enabled) {
  foreach (var pair in m_TextBoxesPairs) {
      pair.Key.Visible = !enabled;
      pair.Key.Visible =  enabled;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But one more thing. In my program it is very irritable that textbox are still selectable and when i select text IBeam cursor still blinking. I have tried to Enable = false but text color is gray even, when i set Color.Black

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            Control[] labels = this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Label)).ToArray() ;
            for(int i = labels.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Label label = (Label)labels[i];
                TextBox newBox = new TextBox();
                newBox.Left = label.Left;
                newBox.Top = label.Top;
                newBox.Width = label.Width;
                newBox.Height = label.Height + 10;
                newBox.Text = label.Text;
                label.Parent.Controls.Add(newBox);
                label.Parent.Controls.Remove(label);
            }
```

Comment: Code searches main form (this).  If labels are in a control then you need to replace this with the parent control.